# boost::shared_ptr, one atomic increment in ctor but two atomic decrements in dtor?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, shared-ptr

I am stepping through the source code for `boost::shared_ptr` and upon construction the reference counter calls atomic increment once. However, on destruction I see that atomic decrement is called twice, connected to the weak reference?

However, how can this work? One increment on construction yet two decrements on destruction, once in `release()` and again in `weak_release()`?

Comment: Can you inlcude the corresponding code sections in your post or include a link?

Answer (score 3):

A shared_ptr has to maintain two reference counts. One for the shared instances and one for possible reference through a weak_ptr. Having this, a weak_ptr is able to increment the weak reference count in the shared_ptr and keep the shared_ptr alive (even after the allocated object is deallocated) to determine a valid conversion from a weak_ptr to a shared_ptr.

Comment: Wouldn't the weak counter initialise to zero and then be -1 after decrementing?

Comment: @mezamorphic That would be an implementation detail.

Answer (score 1):

You are constructing `shared_ptr` without any regard to any weak reference since there could be no such thing as weak reference during `shared_ptr`construction. But on destruction 2 counters should be decremented the main one and the one for the weak references. Clearly after your `shared_ptr` object was created anyone can create `weak_ptr` to it but that can be done only after `shared_ptr` `ctor` completed, not before.

Comment: Wouldn't the weak counter initialise to zero and then be -1 after decrementing?

Comment: It depends on implementation and, frankly, it doesn't matter as long as `-1` is treated as a special value.